Can I be accused of using fake documents for visa after I have received it?
Once issued a Schengen multiple entry visa, and having travelled once, can someone report you to the embassy citing fake documents?  And will the embassy that has already issued visa reopen the file?

I think the linked question was not about fake documents. In any case: your visa can be cancelled or you can get a lot of question and deny entry at entry point: Tampering documents (or giving manifestly fake documents) is a crime. OTOH embassy will not do automatically: there are too many cases of fake reports on fake documents, (just to hinder a travel of someone), and also that is a crime. -- As you see, the step to go to crime (and so not much immigration law) is easy, and then "law SE" is more relevant.

The linked duplicate was by the same poster, so apparently he wasn't satisfied with the answers he got there? I can't understand why though.

You say "travelled also", then you should specify if it's a single or multiple (maybe limited to some number) entry visa. If it's a single entry visa and it has already been used there's no point in revisiting the decision.

Its multiple entry visa

@Henriksupportsthecommunity An annulment would be registered in the VIS, a point could be making sure the fraud is recorded and can be taken into account if the person tries to apply again.

Relaxed: I agree, it's useful to record the fraud. I was only thinking in relation to the visa tthat had already been issued and used.

Yes, there is no reason a consulate could not investigate and annul a visa if they suspect fraud. There is nothing in the regulation that suggest it cannot be done with a spent visa but it is obviously especially relevant for a multiple-entry visa. Whether a given consulate will bother depends on the specifics and is anyone's guess.

IIRC, various countries make it a crime to travel with a visa that you fraudulently acquired, so further charges may happen from that side as well.
